# How to use wildcards with Replace() without using Regex

Tags: c#, replace

I was wondering how to use string replacement without using a Regex. I have a string that is for a YouTube embed link...i.e,

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Zf45Sxlg7Lk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have a container that is a set size and I need to replace the width and height with the size of the container.

```
string myStr = "<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Zf45Sxlg7Lk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
string myStr2;
myStr2 = myStr.Replace("width=''", "width='400'");
```

That doesn't work, so I am assuming that I need to use wildcards with the replace. I have seen examples using Regex, but I was wondering how its done with `String.Replace()`.

I could just use `Remove()`, but I would never be sure that when other videos are embedded, that the embed link would be identical to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.Replace` [does only accept a char or a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will be replaced by new if matches **exactly** in source string. No logic as wildcards.. (only escapes and system property that represents a string - `System.Environment.NewLine`).

The nicest way to replace string is by `RegEx.Replace(myStr, "width=\"\d*\"", "width=\"400\"")` or some variant by your taste.

If you want to avoid `RegEx.Replace`, you can use some combinations of [String methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at your creativity.

You can for example use:
- `String.Split` + `String.Replace` + `String.Join`.
- `String.IndexOf("width=")` + `String.SubString`...

But I bet no one would be so [maintainable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability) and [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) as RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

I may be way out in left field here but what about something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    string myStr = "your url";

    int start = myStr.IndexOf("width='");
    int end = 4; //4 characters after the width size?
    int newSize = 800; // new width size

    string newStr = myStr.Substring(1,start); //first part 
    newStr += newSize.ToString(); // new width size
    newStr += myStr.Substring(start+end, string.length(myStr)); //get the rest of the original string

    //newStr should be the correct 
    //string where you could run the string.Replace on the source



}

// Define other methods and classes here
```

Hope this helps. I think I'm going back to code golf.